# Carregar itens de uma plist

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-3

Estou com dificuldades de carregar os itens de uma property list. Observem minha plist:
[image: directory.plist à esquerda e Outlets à direita]

Aqui minha primeira View Controller:

```
import UIKit

class Page1: UITableViewController {

var filePath: String?
var employees: [[String: Any]] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

    filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "directory", ofType: "plist")
    employees = NSArray(contentsOfFile: filePath!) as! [[String: Any]]

    for item in employees {

        print(item["Name"] as Any)
        print(item.count)
        print(employees.count)
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return employees.count
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? Page2,
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        destination.itemSelecionado = employees[indexPath.row]
        tableView .deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    cell.nameLabel.text = (employees[indexPath.row]["Name"] as! String)
    cell.positionLabel.text = (employees[indexPath.row]["Position"] as! String)

        return cell
    }
}
```

Aqui minha segunda View Controller:

```
import UIKit

class Page2: UITableViewController {

var itemSelecionado: [Page1] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemSelecionado.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell2
    cell.emailLabel.text = (itemSelecionado.employees[indexPath.row]["Email"] as! String )
    cell.phoneLabel.text = (itemSelecionado.employees[indexPath.row]["Phone"] as! String? )

    return cell
    }   
}
```

O Xcode está me retornando 3 erros, são eles:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, não compreendo o motivo destes erros, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Desde já, obrigado!

---

Problema ao tentar inserir imagem: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Explique exatamente qual o resultado você está querendo, pois eu consegui enxergar duas possibilidades, mas que iriam gerar alterações diferentes.

Comment: Quero um app que se apresente em 2 TableViews. A 1ª vai apresentar o nome e a função do funcionário e, ao tocar em determinado funcionário, a 2ª irá apresentar detalhes do mesmo, telefone, e-mail e outros itens que vou adicionar depois.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você esta tentando acessar uma propriedade interna do seu view controller Page1 no ViewController Page2. Se você precisar acessar uma variável de maneira global faz o seguinte:

Crie uma estrutura para agrupar as sua variáveis "globais" (compartilhadas) e adicione uma propriedade estática `instance`, declare ali o seu array de employees  e outras propriedades que você achar necessário.

```
struct Shared {
    static var instance = Shared()
    var employees: [Employee] = []
}
```

Crie uma estrutura com um init personalizado para facilitar a criação das suas estruturas:

```
struct Employee {
    let position: String
    let name: String
    let email: String
    let phone: String
    init(dictionary: [String: String]) {
        self.position = dictionary["Position"] ?? ""
        self.name = dictionary["Name"] ?? ""
        self.email = dictionary["Email"] ?? ""
        self.phone = dictionary["Phone"] ?? ""
    }
}
```

Assim voce pode ler a plist dentro do método didFinishLaunchingWithOptions na sua classe AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "directory", withExtension: "plist"), let array = NSArray(contentsOf: url) as? [[String: String]] {
        Shared.instance.employees = array.map{Employee(dictionary: $0)}
    }
    return true
}
```

E visualizar os employees em qualquer view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Shared.instance.employees.forEach({
            print("name:", $0.name)
            print("position:", $0.position)
            print("phone:", $0.phone)
            print("email:", $0.email)
            print()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h1bzehot1tac1v2/plist%20sample.zip?dl=1

Comment: Cara, me ajudou muito!! Era exatamente o que eu precisava! Muito obrigado!! Só uma dúvida final: se eu alterar o *root* do plist para **dictionary**, basta alterar o NSArray do AppDelegate para NSDicitionary?

Comment: Sim use NSArray(contentsOf:) pra array e NSDictionary(contentsOf:) pra dicionarios

Comment: Tentei inserir uma imagem na estrutura Employee, fiz desse jeito:
    let image: UIImage
    …
    self.image = dictionary["image"] ?? ""

Mas ele fica acusando erro. Alguma ideia?
Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver aqueles problemas, porém agora surgiram outros. Não estou conseguindo receber os dados na minha TableViewController.

Fiz da seguinte forma: primeiro criei uma *variável* para receber a Struct **Shared**:

```
var item1: Shared!
```

Depois de definir o *numberOfSections* e o *numberOfRowsInSection*, acho que coloquei alguma informação incorreta no *dequeueReusableCell*. Mas não sei o que foi. Veja o que fiz:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    cell.nameLabel.text = (item1.employees[indexPath.row]["Name"] as? String)
    cell.positionLabel.text = (item1.employees[indexPath.row]["Position"] as? String)
```

Nas duas últimas linhas abaixo ele informa:

**Type 'Employee' has no subscript members**

Não consegui identificar o que coloquei errado.

Comment: Melhor você abrir outra pergunta que eu dou uma olhada quando estiver com o Mac na minha frente

Comment: Você não precisa instantiate a estrutura. Você vai sempre usar a Shared.instance.whatever

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41560949/2303865

Comment: `cell.nameLabel.text = Shared.instance.employees[indexPath.row].nome`

Comment: Estava só faltando eu colocar o **.name**. Consegui resolver tudo graças a você, muito obrigado camarada!!

Comment: porque voce nao usa um array pros funcs em vez de dicionario?

Comment: Não tinha cogitado, mas neste caso o que eu mudo no App Delegate e na Struct?

Comment: troquei pra dicionario. se quiser colocar alguma imagem no seu dicionario basta colocar o nome da imagem que ta no asset depois é só adicionar uma propriedade pra imagem `let image: UIImage` e inicializa dentro do init da struct usando `self.image = UIImage(named: imageName)`

Comment: imageName voce coloca em algum lugar na sua plist

Comment: Editei a pergunta mostrando o problema que surge no `Struct` quando tento inserir imagem.

Comment: usa a string pra inicializar a UIImage

Comment: `self.image = UIImage(named: (dicionary["image"] as? String ?? ""))!`

Comment: cuidado com o uso da exclamação. Certifique de que existe uma imagem no seu asset com o nome que voce armazenou na plist

Comment: me passa as imagens e o plist atualizado que eu corrijo aqui o que for necessário e atualizo o projeto e a resposta

Comment: Eu to apanhando um pouco aqui, mas até que tá dando pra desenrolar. Como faço pra te mandar? O problema que surgiu agora é que no final estou lançando tudo numa TableView, isso não foi problema, até ter que inserir uma imagem no interior do `Details` na célula… enfim, to achando meio difícil de explicar por aqui, sem mostrar.

Comment: por isso que nao se deve fazer perguntas no comentário. Não tem como voce detalhar o suficiente :) Abre outra pergunta e vai seguindo o seu passo a passo

Comment: @LeoDabus beleza, vou fazer isso com mais calma. De qualquer forma, obrigado pela força, camarada!

Comment: Criei: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193091/como-receber-dados-de-subitens-de-uma-plist