# Como receber dados de subitens de uma plist?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Boas! Estou com dificuldade em receber dados de subitens de minha plist. Observem…
Esta é minha `directory.plist`:
[image: directory.plist]

Eu quero jogar tudo isso aqui nesta `Main.storyboard`:
[image: Main.storyboard]

Sendo que as keys `Position` e `Name` ficariam na primeira **TableViewController** e as keys `Functionary`, `ImageFace` e `Phone` ficariam na segunda **TableViewController**.

Para isso eu fiz o seguinte:

1. Adicionei ao **AppDelegate** o seguinte:

   ```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "directory", withExtension: "plist"), let array = NSArray(contentsOf: url) as? [[String:Any]] {
           Shared.instance.employees = array.map{Employee(dictionary: $0)}
   }
   return true
   ```
2. Minha `Struct` ficou dessa forma:

   ```
   struct EmployeeDetails {
       let functionary: String
       let imageFace: String
       let phone: String

       init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
           self.functionary = (dictionary["Functionary"] as? String) ?? ""
           self.imageFace = (dictionary["ImageFace"] as? String) ?? ""
           self.phone = (dictionary["Phone"] as? String) ?? ""
       }
   }

   struct Employee {
       let position: String
       let name: String
       let details: [EmployeeDetails] // [String:Any]

       init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
       self.position = (dictionary["Position"] as? String) ?? ""
       self.name = (dictionary["Name"] as? String) ?? ""

       let t = (dictionary["Details"] as? [Any]) ?? []
       self.details = t.map({EmployeeDetails(dictionary: $0 as! [String : Any])})
       }
   }

   struct Shared {
       static var instance = Shared()
       var employees: [Employee] = []
   }
   ```
3. Meu **primeiro TableViewController**, ficou assim:

   ```
   class Page1: UITableViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let anEmployee = Shared.instance.employees[1]

       print("Name:", anEmployee.name)
       print("Position:", anEmployee.position)

       anEmployee.details.forEach({

           print("Functionary:", $0.functionary)
           print("ImageFace:", $0.imageFace)
           print("Phone:", $0.phone)
       })
   }

   override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   return 1
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return Shared.instance.employees.count
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell1

           cell.nameLabel.text = Shared.instance.employees[indexPath.row].name
           cell.positionLabel.text = Shared.instance.employees[indexPath.row].position

           return cell
       }

   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       if let destination = segue.destination as? Page2,
           let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
           destination.newPage = Shared.instance.employees[indexPath.row].details[indexPath.row]
           tableView .deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Meu **segundo TableViewController**, ficou assim:

   ```
   var newPage: EmployeeDetails! //recently added

   class Page2: UITableViewController {

   var newPage: EmployeeDetails!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       if let theEmployee = newPage {
           self.title = theEmployee.name
       }
   }

   override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       return 1
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       if let theEmployee = newPage {
           return theEmployee.details.count
       }
   return 0
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell2

       if let theEmployee = newPage {

           cell.faceImage.image = theEmployee.details[indexPath.row].imageFace as? UIImage // did not work
           cell.functionary.text = theEmployee.details[indexPath.row].functionary
           cell.phoneLabel.text = theEmployee.details[indexPath.row].phone
       }
       return cell
       }
   }
   ```

Após as alterações, o projeto não apresenta mais erros, porém a 2ª TableViewController permanece vazia! A Debug Area diz o seguinte:

```
2017-03-28 17:16:28.456 plist sample[7138:425253] Unknown class Page2 in Interface Builder file.
```

Alguma ideia?

Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: Voce esqueceu de postar a `struct Employee`

Comment: Pronto! Obrigado por lembrar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá,

Acredito que seu primeiro problema (`"Está retornando nil"`) é que a propriedade `details` na sua struct `Employee` é um dicionário do tipo `[String:Any]`, porém na sua .plist ela é uma **array** de dicionários. Logo, o correto seria `[[String:Any]]`.

Seu segundo problema está relacionado com o primeiro, pois se o `details` é uma array, ela não possui o `subscript` que você referencia (o que gera este *compile error*).

Sendo assim, a sintaxe correta para você extrair o valor do campo da sua .plist (como ela está, *ipsis literis*) seria (exemplo):

```
cell.faceImage.image = Shared.instance.employees[indexPath.row].details[<!INDEX!>]["ImageFace"]
```

Substitua `<!INDEX!>` para o índice correto.

**UPDATE**

Para enviar o objeto selecionado na sua primeira VC par a segunda VC, você deve implementar ambos os métodos `func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` e `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`.

Exemplos:

1) Ao selecionar uma célula da tabela:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let object = Shared.instance.employees[indexPath.row]
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ID_DA_SEGUE_AQUI", sender: object)
}
```

2) Carregar a próxima tabela com o dado selecionado:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if  let proximoVc = segue.destination as?  {
        proximoVc.newPage = sender as? EmployeeDetails
    }
}
```

**Obs.:** O código acima pode gerar um *crash* caso o índice na busca dentro da array não esteja correto. Verifique se as referências estão corretas antes de prosseguir.

Comment: Cara, funcionou legal! A debug area está recebendo os itens legal. Mas a 2ª TableViewController não recebe os subitens da `directory.plist`. Alguma ideia camarada?

Comment: Você precisa implementar o método `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`.

Comment: Já fiz e atualizei a pergunta, porém minha 2ª TableView continua vazia. Não sei o que está errado.

Comment: Oi Arnon, atualizei minha resposta com essa implementação. Foquei em lhe demonstrar os métodos que precisam ser subscritos e suas respectivas implementações. Ignorei se o índice `indexPath.row` faz a correta referência ao objeto selecionado. Favor substituir essa parte para aquilo que mais lhe convir. Abs

Comment: valeu camarada! Segui tuas dicas! Tudo resolvido!! VALEU